# Anagrams with sequences inside

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need some help with this exercise:

Find the number of anagrams of the word “MONOCROMO” containing atleast one of the sequences “OMO”, “MON”, “CRO”.

Normally I know what to do, but in this one there are some cases i don't know how to handle. Please give me a hand, I need to be able to explain this tomorrow and I'm not sure if this works how i think it does.

The idea is to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion, so i call
$A$ = "OMO"
$B$ = "CRO"
$C$ = "MON"

|A$\cup$B$\cup$C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A$\cap$B| - |A$\cap$C| - |B$\cap$C| + |A$\cap$B$\cap$C|

So, $|MONOCROMO|$ are $\frac{9!}{4!2!}$ since there are 4 "O" and 2 "M"

I'll write just the cases I don't know how to solve, to spare you a longer and boring read.

$|A|$ = OMO, N, C, R, $O$, $M$, $O$ = $\frac{7!}{2!}$
but I can see another "OMO" that is free. I am not sure how to handle this case.
I think I would do something like
OMO, OMO,  N, C, R = $-3!{5 \choose 2}$.

Ok, so what i understand here is that i have OMO, OMO, N, C, R.
${5 \choose 2}$ is the number of words that contains 2 sequences of "OMO"
$3!$ is the number of other letters wich i can permute. So i get $\frac{7!}{2!} -3!{5 \choose 2}$ is this correct?

|A$\cap$B| = OMO, CRO, M, N, O = ${5!}$
also CROMO, M, O, N, O = $\frac{5!}{2!}$
but also CROMO, OMO, N = $3!$ ?
and then OMOMO, CRO N =
and CROMOMO, N, O =
I am not sure at all about this one, i hope it works this way but is really messy in my head if i have to subtract what i find or add it...

|A$\cap$C| = OMO, MON, C, R, O = $5!$
Also OMON, C, R, $O$, $M$, $O$ = $\frac{6!}{2!}$
And also OMON, OMO, C, R = $4!$ ?
And OMOMON, C, R, O =
Again, the same case.

I hope this is understandable, I am new of math stackexchange and i tried to find the right syntax and words to write, also I am not native english speaker, so I am sorry if I made any mistakes.
Also i deleted my previous post and made this new one.

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Sequences containing OMO at least once: OMO, M, N, C, R, O, O: $\frac{7!}{2!}$.

b) Sequences with two disjoint OMOs: OMO, OMO, N, C, R: $\frac{5!}{2!}$.

c) Sequences with overlapping OMOs, i.e. OMOMO, N, C, R, O: $5!$.

In summary, there are $\frac{7!}{2!} -\frac{5!}{2!}-5!$ sequences with at least one OMO. But there are awfully many more special cases to count and to check which are double counted where, which to add, which to suctract.
All in all I rely more in a quick programmatic count that gives me $4574$ as answer (so tehre's something to check against).

d) CRO, N, M, M, O, O, O:$\frac{7!}{2!3!}$

e) CRO, OMO, N, M, O: $5!$

f) CRO, MON, M, O, O:  $\frac{5!}{2!}$

g) CRO, MON, OMO: $3!$

h) MON, C, R, M, O, O, O: $\frac{7!}{3!}$

i) MON, OMO, C, R, O: $5!$

j) CROMO, N, M, O, O: $\frac{5!}{2!}$

k) CROMO, MON, O: $3!$

l) CRO, OMON, M, O: $4!$

m) CRO, OMOMO, N: $3!$

n) CRO, OMOMON: $2!$

o) CROMON, M, O, O: $\frac{4!}{2!}$

p) CROMON, OMO: $2!$

q) CROMOMO, N, O: $3!$

r) CROMOMON, O: $2!$

Comment: Thanks, I am  starting to make sense of what i didn't get.  And thanks for making me notice i forgot all the OMOMON ones.

Comment: Do sequences of the type (or even this specifically) OMON, C, R, O, M, O count? Or must they be interpreted simply as OMON, OMO, C, R?
To be more clear, when i have OMO $\cap$ MON, i would get $5!$ - $6!/2!$ and more, but i'm not sure that can happen since it goes negative

Comment: FYI, this is the (at least) third time that OP has posted this question, and deleted the other copies. I did previously mention that he was missing those with 2 "OMO", but he just wanted someone to do all the work for him.

Comment: @Calvin FYI, I deleted them because after 2 days there where 2 comments which, after i responded to them, never wrote back. Also i'd like you to notice that the two post i deleted had more upvotes than this one. My motivation was only understand the part i didn't know get. Also please notice that i posted how I tried to solve the problem in it's entirety, and at that point i had nothing more to go on to solve it, since the cases I needed help with were obviously the ones i could not solve. You commented one of my previous post and I answered asking you to simplify it, what else could i do?